# Dependent dropdown in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to create a cost estimation form in WordPress using custom code and I am a beginner in PHP, AJAX, and MYSQL so I need help in the below query.

Basically need to create a dependent dropdown for Car Make and Car Model so I have created one dab table call `wp_cost_estimation` which has `id`, `make`, `make_id`, `model`. See the below image.

[image]

So if the user selects Acura in the next drop down it should show all the Acura models without repetition.
I tried the below code.
Please correct me where I am wrong.

**cost_estimation_template.php**

```
 <select placeholder="Select Make" name="make" id="make">
              <option disabled="" selected="">--Select Make--</option>
              <?php

                    include get_theme_file_path( '/data.php' );
                    $makes = loadMake();

                    foreach ($makes as $make) {
                                    echo "<option id='".$make['id']."' value='".$make['id']."'>".$make['make']."</option>";
                                }
              ?>
            </select>

  <select placeholder="Select Model" name="model" id="model">
              <option disabled="" selected="">--Select Model--</option>

            </select>
```

**data.php**

```
 if(isset($_POST['aid'])) {
    $db = new DbConnect;
    $conn = $db->connect();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT model_name FROM wp_cost_estimation WHERE make_id = " . $_POST['aid'] GROUP BY model_name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $models = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($models);
}

 
  function loadMake() {
    $db = new DbConnect;
    $conn = $db->connect();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT MIN(id) AS id, make FROM wp_cost_estimation GROUP BY make");
    $stmt->execute();
    $make = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $make;
}
```

**AJAX Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#make").change(function(){
            var aid = $("#make").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo get_theme_file_path('/data.php'); ?>',
                method: 'post',
                data: 'aid=' + aid
            }).done(function(model){
                console.log(model);
                model = JSON.parse(model);
                $('#model').empty();
                model.forEach(function(models){
                $('#model').append('<option>' + models.model_name + '</option>')
                })
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: what doesn't work ? are you getting any error ?

Comment: As of now its not showing any errors but it is not even showing result i want

Comment: I think the problem is here `get_theme_file_path('/data.php')`. Could you please show what return this function?

Comment: Also you can see here some example - https://gist.github.com/devinsays/69a305053e35a10584f94d6011bba2d6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using WordPress, you'll definitely want to give the [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and [J.A.jQ](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/) Codex a thorough read, you're not really using **any** of the benefits of WordPress if your existing code.

The two biggest things you'd want to take advantage of here are the [`wp_ajax_{$action}()` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/) and the `$wpdb` class.

The `wp_ajax_` (and `wp_ajax_nopriv_`) hooks allow you to easily run functions with specific actions, and the `$wpdb` class handles the *vast majority* (read: all) of the database connection and interactions that you'll need. And you can drop almost all of this in your `functions.php` file (or a plugin file, or [Must Use Plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/) file)

I've taken the liberty of setting up a working example here: https://xhynk.com/content-mask/65517584-answer/

Here's what the `functions.php` file looks like:

```
function loadMake(){
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT MIN(id) AS id, make FROM cm_test_make_model GROUP BY make" );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    wp_enqueue_script( '65517584', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/65517584.js', [], filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/assets/scripts/65517584.js'), true );

    $localize = array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
    wp_localize_script( '65517584', 'ajax_object', $localize );
});

add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_models', 'load_models' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_models', 'load_models' );
function load_models(){
    if( isset($_POST['aid']) ){
        global $wpdb;
        
        $sql = "SELECT model_name FROM cm_test_make_model WHERE make_id = %d GROUP BY model_name";
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, array( absint($_POST['aid']) ) ) );

        wp_send_json( $results, 200 );
    } else {
        wp_send_json( array('message', 'aid is required'), 400 );
    }
}
```

You'll note the `loadMake()` function uses `$wpdb` to make the simple query (I also changed the table name to fit mine)

It's also enqueuing the JavaScript file, and [localizes it with `wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) to pass the appropriate AJAX URL to it (this is also how you can pass along other data from PHP to your JS handler).

The last part uses the `wp_ajax_` hooks to run the `load_models` function, and uses `$wpdb`'s helper functions to prepare the statement, and [`wp_send_json`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/) to convert it to JSON, print it out, and then die. (*IT IS VERY IMPORTANT TO KILL THE REQUEST WITH DIE/EXIT AFTER RUNNING A FUNCTION VIA AJAX*. If you `echo` out the json manually, you'll need to call `die` or `exit` after.)

Below is the enqueued JavaScript file (note, I enqueued this relative to my theme, you may need to change the URL that's enqueued above if yours is in a different location:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#make").change(function(){
        var aid = $("#make").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_object.ajax_url + '?action=load_models',
            method: 'post',
            data: 'aid=' + aid
        }).done(function(models){
            $('#model').empty();
            models.forEach(function(model){
                console.log( model );
                $('#model').append('<option>' + model.model_name + '</option>');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

You can see the URL is using the localized variable we passed along.

Lastly, I made a simple Page Template that has the selects on it. Note that `wp_enqueue_scripts` requires `wp_head()` on the page, and if using the `$in_footer` option of `wp_enqueue_script()` you'll need `wp_footer()` as well:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<select placeholder="Select Make" name="make" id="make">
    <option disabled="" selected="">--Select Make--</option>
    <?php
        $makes = loadMake();
        foreach( $makes as $make ){
            printf( '<option id="%d" value="%d">%s</option>', $make->id, $make->id, $make->make );
        }
    ?>
</select>

<select placeholder="Select Model" name="model" id="model">
    <option disabled="" selected="">--Select Model--</option>
</select>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

A bit long-winded (sorry!) but you'll really want to make use of WordPress' ecosystem if you're going to be using it. And again, here's the link to the working example using the code above: https://xhynk.com/content-mask/65517584-answer/ which uses the following database structure: [image: this database structure]

Comment: Thank you so much give me some time to implement will let you know if it worked or not.

Comment: Thanks thanks alot i can't tell you how important it was for me to complete this by today.

Comment: My pleasure, I'm glad I was able to help! Props for being able to move from traditional PHP/Ajax to WordPress's as well - (I know from experience it can be a bit daunting), but once you get the hang of it, it really does make it a lot easier to manage dynamic interactions like this. Cheers!

Comment: I hope some day i will be as pro as you are today. Happy New year in advance.