# Dynamically generate select element's options from wpdb based on previous select element's value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I have this select element that generates an option for each row in a table that matches certain criteria:

```
<select id="add-item-category-input" name="add-items-category" type="text">
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $categories_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'mp_inventory_categories';
    $categories = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $categories_table WHERE cat_type = %s", 'main')
    );

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        echo '<option value="' . $category->sku_ident . '">';
        $name = explode("_", $category->category_name);
        foreach ($name as $part) {
            echo ucfirst($part) . " ";
        }
        echo '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

I need an additional select element that generates an option for every row in the same categories table that has a 'parent'  = to the selected category's value and a cat_type = 'sub'.

I know it's possible to dynamically generate content based on a selected option using ajax, but I think I can access the wpdb using js.

Comment: What seems to go wrong?

Comment: @maxipoo you can not access $wpdb with just Javascript. JS is client-base, MySQL is server based. As you already said you would need AJAX. If you don't want to to do an AJAX call, on every change of the parent select, then you would have to bring all possible options on the initial load and selectively show-hide the appropriate options. In a really big dataset that won't be efficient and better to do a query onChange.

Comment: [Dependent dropdown in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65517584/1427878) should give you a good idea on how to get this done.